# Detect if two tasks collide in java

Tags: java, time, feasibility

I have the following case: Two tasks, *A* and *B*, each with a given time window that specifies the earliest time the task can start, called `earliestStart` and the latest time the task can end, called `latestEnd`. In addition, the tasks have a given `duration`, that is equal or less than `latestEnd - earliestStart` for that specific task. E.g task `A` has to be performed within `08:00-10:00` and the duration is 1 hour, while task `B` has to be performed within `08:50-09:55`, and the duration is 1 hour. How can I check this easily in java, is this correct? (to prove that they are not overlapping):

```
taskA.earliestStart + taskA.duration < taskB.latestEnd - taskB.duration 
|| taskB.earliestStart + taskB.duration < taskA.latestEnd - taskA.duration
```

Comment: Yes, for two tasks that is correct (if you had 3 tasks, it would be more complicated). I recommend that you use the code you have as pseudocode and implement it using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) to represent a time-of-day without date and without time zone.

```
LocalTime aStart = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ;
Duration aDuration = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;
LocalTime aStop = aStart.plus( aDuration ) ;
```

Compare using `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `equals` methods.